# Load all materials with loadallassetbundles before objects?

Tags: unity, shaders, assets, materials

I have a lot of objects as assetbundles and they're growing.
I didn't want to have the user to download the materials for every asset because they all share their materials. so I put all the materials in an `assetbundle` and load it by `LoadAllAssets()` in the `Awake()` function so they are present in the game for the assets to use.
The problem is that asset load without materials. the ones that have material don't have shader. Is `LoadAllAssets()` not the answer? what should I do?